# fix Eclipse ctrl-click to search same class space as ctrl-shift-T

Tags: java, eclipse

Sometimes I find that Eclipse can't find certain class source files when I ctrl-click a classname in source code, even while finding it via ctrl-shift-T (typing the class name) works fine.

Is there a way to set ctrl-click to use the same search path as ctrl-shift-T?

Eclipse Version: Neon Milestone 1 (4.6.0M1)
Build id: 20150820-1211

[EDIT: to clarify, I'm aware I can probably resolve my issue by attaching source, etc.  But the point is I don't want to have two separate search paths here -- since ctrl-shift-T already works fully and takes me to the correct source code, this means that Eclipse DOES at some level already know where the source code is.  Therefore I want to latch onto that rather than manually configuring it a second time]

Comment: What happens when the ctrl+click fails?

Comment: @Kon it says "Source not found" and takes me to a decompiled version of the class

Comment: You need to attach the source manually. You probably have multiple JARs, some of which have source and some that don't. My guess is CTRL+SHIFT+T only shows those files for which you have source available, but when you CTRL+CLICK it uses whatever is at the top of the classpath. Just a complete guess. For me, I was not able to reproduce your issue on a very complex setup.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell eclipse where the source for that class is located.  When you go to the definition currently, you are accessing it through the jar dependency.  When you use `ctrl+shift+t` you are looking up the actual source file in a different location.  You need to connect the two.  When you open the decompiled class, there should be a button that says "attach source..."  Click the button and navigate to where the source for the class is.